# How can I replace all the characters from a string?

Tags: sed

I have the following string

```
signaldate signaltime period UwThiSon3dH140__mean UwThiSon3dH140__sigma
```

I tried to use `sed` to replace the space with comma.

```
sed 's/ /,/g'
sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g'
```

but it the output still the original string. How can I replace that white space?

Comment: try this http://superuser.com/a/112837/160311

Comment: unfortunately not working.

Comment: Your `sed` commands should have worked if the space is really a space character or even a TAB. Pass your string to `hexdump` to find the exact content of it and the hexadecimal translation of the character that you may think is a space. You can add the dump to your question too.

Comment: Could you also share in your question how you proceed : full command with all the pipes and so on, your script, ...

Comment: run, did you paste literally the command from the link I posted? If so sed was searching for 3 consecutive spaces. For single space remove the \{3,\} part of the regex.

Comment: No, I deleted the {3}, is there a possibility to replace all that character which not a-z A-Z 0-9 and _ with sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem?

```
$ echo signaldate signaltime period UwThiSon3dH140__mean UwThiSon3dH140__sigma \
  | sed 's/ /,/g'
signaldate,signaltime,period,UwThiSon3dH140__mean,UwThiSon3dH140__sigma
```

Perhaps what you're seeing isn't whitespace or it's mixed whitespace. Try the `\s` character instead:

```
$ echo signaldate signaltime period UwThiSon3dH140__mean UwThiSon3dH140__sigma \
  | sed 's/\s/,/g'
signaldate,signaltime,period,UwThiSon3dH140__mean,UwThiSon3dH140__sigma
```

Failing that, do as your question's comments suggest and pass the output through `hexdump` so you can see what's really going on because it's not a space.

---

Note that you could also use `tr` to replace the character but I doubt that's going to fix your issue if you can't get `sed` working:

```
$ echo signaldate signaltime period UwThiSon3dH140__mean UwThiSon3dH140__sigma \
  | tr ' ' ','
signaldate,signaltime,period,UwThiSon3dH140__mean,UwThiSon3dH140__sigma
```

Answer (score 1):

`\s` matches a single space or a tab. It won't match if there is two spaces in the input string. So it's better to use `<space>+` in the pattern.

```
$ echo 'signaldate signaltime period UwThiSon3dH140__mean UwThiSon3dH140__sigma' | sed 's/ \+/,/g'
signaldate,signaltime,period,UwThiSon3dH140__mean,UwThiSon3dH140__sigma
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `comma` operator like this.

`sed 's/ /\,/g'`

I checked the same in my solaris system,

```
  bash-3.2$ echo "signaldate signaltime period UwThiSon3dH140__mean     UwThiSon3dH140__sigma" | sed 's/ /\,/g'
  signaldate,signaltime,period,UwThiSon3dH140__mean,UwThiSon3dH140__sigma
  bash-3.2$
```

Comment: No, you don't need to escape the comma.

Comment: hi @Oli, when i checked without escaping it failed give the required output in my system. So i suggested to use escape character.